# Fill a 2D array with integers?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i populate a 2D array? I know how to populate a single dimension array but having issues...

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        array.length[i, j] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your issues, aside from the fact that you seem to be programming in Java?

Comment: Java#. My favourite language!

Comment: The declaration of `array` is critical here, post it. Also include error all error messages, this mig just be `length` vs `length`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method `GetLength(int dimension)` not the simple getter `Length` to have the length of the two dimensions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just about to post that. Example here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/9vyREh

Comment: brilliant thanks so much, will accept answer when it lets me (in 3 minutes) :)

Comment: I assume it's due to a lack of basic understanding of the problem domain.